# Unable to find the connection profile reference by DS connection properties in BIRT report

Tags: postgresql, centos, birt, birt-deapi

I am completely new to Birt Report.
I have generated a "***.rptdesign***" file and it get the data from postgres then generated the Birt report. I have deployed same file into  path "**/home/ram/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/birt**"
 from **Ubuntu OS** and dbconnection profile file also same path.Now I openthe browser hit the following url
***http://ram.com:8080/birt/frameset?__report=report.rptdesign***
It throwing an Exception. Some one facing the same issues? How to resolve the bug?

**Exception:**

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details: Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile. org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Unable to find the connection profile referenced by the data source connection properties. ; org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Unable to find or access the named profile (reportsource) in profile store path (/home/ram/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/birt/dbsource). ; org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ; java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine the default workspace location. Check your OSGi-less platform configuration of the plugin or datatools workspace path. (Element ID:9)
```

[image]

**Stack Trace:**

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile.
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Unable to find the connection profile referenced by the data source connection properties. ;
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Unable to find or access the named profile (reportsource) in profile store path (/home/ram/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/birt/dbsource). ;
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ;
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine the default workspace location. Check your OSGi-less platform configuration of the plugin or datatools workspace path. (Element ID:9)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1237)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1216)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:96)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportItemEmitterExecutor.execute(ReportItemEmitterExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilder.java:258)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:262)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:86)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1325)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:158)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists(BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:119)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:104)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor296.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy642.doFilter(Unknown Source)
   at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
   at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
   at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
   at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
   at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
   at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
   at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.api.AdapterException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile.
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Unable to find the connection profile referenced by the data source connection properties. ;
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Unable to find or access the named profile (reportsource) in profile store path (/home/ram/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/birt/dbsource). ;
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ;
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine the default workspace location. Check your OSGi-less platform configuration of the plugin or datatools workspace path.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:644)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataGenerationEngine.doExecuteQuery(DataGenerationEngine.java:83)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:267)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1939)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
... 75 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile.
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Unable to find the connection profile referenced by the data source connection properties. ;
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Unable to find or access the named profile (reportsource) in profile store path (/home/ram/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/birt/dbsource). ;
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ;
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine the default workspace location. Check your OSGi-less platform configuration of the plugin or datatools workspace path.
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.newException(ExceptionHandler.java:54)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:177)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSource.java:224)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:212)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(DataSourceRuntime.java:217)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:407)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:317)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:455)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:145)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:624)
... 80 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Unable to find the connection profile referenced by the data source connection properties. ;
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Unable to find or access the named profile (reportsource) in profile store path (/home/ram/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/birt/dbsource). ;
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ;
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine the default workspace location. Check your OSGi-less platform configuration of the plugin or datatools workspace path.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile.impl.Connection.open(Connection.java:109)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile.impl.Connection.open(Connection.java:62)
   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.open(OdaConnection.java:250)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:165)
... 90 more
```